# ASP - Permission denied

Tags: asp-classic, iis-6

before I start, I'm a PHP programmer, not an ASP programmer, but at my job, they use ASP and I don't have acces to the server, but I can contact the person in charge.

I'm working on an ASP function for work and I alway hit this "Permission denied" error. I made some search and I found that the account need permission to run the script. It's maybe just me, but I don't understand that ASP check the user before run a script, I mean, it's a public website, obviously they will not have acces if I don't.

Can I change the file so anyone can run it ?

EDIT : 
My script is trying to edit a file on the server

```
dim fs,f
set fs=Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
set f=fs.OpenTextFile(Server.MapPath("test.txt"),8,true)
f.WriteLine("This text will be added to the end of file")
f.Close
set f=Nothing
set fs=Nothing
```

Thanks

Comment: Need more information.  What is the script trying to do?  Access local files or directories?  Create files?  As is, this is unanswerable.

Comment: The account that IIS uses (probably iusr) needs to have read/write permissions on the target folder.  I would recommend using a temp folder (anything other than the website's root folder)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I got the same error if I target a folder. Actually, I don't know if it's possible to skip the account check and just run the script, I think it's more a problem because I don't understand ASP then an error in my code.

Comment: By default, the account will have no permissions, so of course, you wouldn't be able to target a folder either.  That's simply basic security.  You need to have whoever administers that machine give permissions on an appropriate location.

Comment: Oh, I see, I just send an email to the admin to check this out. Thank you for your help.

Comment: and added to this if your are using IIS 7.x some other problems occurs, related more with the UAC than the permissions itself

Comment: @CMKanode this should be an answer. :)

Comment: Certainly @ShadowWizard, I'll do that. I've combined two comments into an answer.

Comment: Cheers @CMKanode now let's hope it will indeed solve Mr. Blowingfish problem and he'll be able to mark this properly as the accepted answer. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The account that IIS uses (probably iusr) needs to have read/write permissions on the target folder. I would recommend using a temp folder (anything other than the website's root folder)

By default, the account will have no permissions.  That's simply basic security. You need to have whoever administers that machine give permissions on an appropriate location.

Comment: Thank you, my script is working now. :D And yeah, it was just because I don't know much about IIS and ASP, my bad!

Comment: @Blowingfish, glad it's working for you now.  IMO, classic ASP is dying out, and last time I used it, I had a much more difficult time getting it set up properly in IIS 6+.  Truthfully, I never want to touch it again!  :)

Comment: @CMKanode Reading this in 2023 is painful. I just got a contract with classic ASP and I only wish classic ASP died faster.